# 404 Error on existing pages with existing routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-404

## *The Problem*

`404 Error` on `https://localhost:44300/services` when pages and routes exist.

---

## *The Question*

What is causing this routing issue?

---

## *Noted Observations*

What I can't understand is how the directory for things like `https://localhost:44300/` & `https://localhost:44300/articles` are the only things that work.

---

## *GitHub Project*

https://github.com/josephmcasey/me

---

## *Files of Interest*

#### /Areas/Article/ArticleRegistrationArea.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JosephMCasey.Areas.Article
{
    public class ArticleAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Article";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Article",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

#### /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace JosephMCasey
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("images/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("ckeditor/{*pathInfo}");

            // access TermsController/Index via /terms
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Terms",
                url: "terms",
                defaults: new { controller = "Terms", action = "Index" }
            );

            // access PrivacyController/Index via /privacy
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Privacy",
                url: "privacy",
                defaults: new { controller = "Privacy", action = "Index" }
            );

            // access ServicesController/Index via /services
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Services",
                url: "services",
                defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
            );

            // access ErrorController/NotFound via /404
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "NotFound",
                url: "404",
                defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }
            );

            // default route (last)
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

#### /Global.asax

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace JosephMCasey
{
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

#### /Controllers/ServicesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JosephMCasey.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ServicesController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

#### /Views/Services/index.cshtml

```
@section SPAViews {
    @Html.Partial("_Services")
}
@section Scripts{
    @*
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
    *@
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Privacy";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "";
    ViewBag.Description = "";
    ViewBag.Created = "";
    ViewBag.Thumbnail = "";
    ViewBag.Image = "";
    ViewBag.TwitterCard = "";
    ViewBag.Site = "";
    ViewBag.URL = "";
    ViewBag.ImageHeight = "";
    ViewBag.ImageWidth = "";
    ViewBag.Site = "";
    ViewBag.Creator = "";
    ViewBag.OGType = "";
}
```

#### /Views/Services/_Services.cshtml

```
<section class="bg-lake light row shelve">
</section>
```

---

Comment: Have you tried using RouteDebugger (nuget package) to see if the route you're expecting to be hit is what the routing is actually hitting?

Comment: I haven't. I didn't even know about this. I've been using CodeMaid and Web Essentials. I'll definitely check that out to see if it brings up anything. My biggest problem is fixing something without an error message.

Comment: Thanks @KarenB ! I got my answer because of you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a default ASP.Net MVC 5 project then this might be helpful information for you. First a foremost, the RouteDebugger Nuget Package is a great tool even 3 years after its last update. It easily pointed out my mistakes.

---

## Global.Asax

First, notice how `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` is placed before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`. Routes take priority by order of the route configurations they receive. AreaRegistration takes precedence over RouteConfig.

---

## RouteConfig.cs & ArticleAreaRegistration.cs

Next, the `Article and Portfolio areas` are using the same route configuration as the

```
        // default route (last)
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Therefore, the services route which comes after these two will not work due to ArticleAreaRegistration coming first.